# Retrieving all image files in jpeg format to specified file in computer

Tags: file, binary, jpeg

i have a question abaout image file stored to db as binary. i have 300 workers profile images stored to database as binary and i want these image re-create as jpeg and save to a file in computer using C#. Can you show me a way about this?

Comment: You're going to need a lot more details. What DB for example? What format are the images stored in?

Comment: the images stored to database as binary and i want retrieve them as jpeg or gif format. is it possible? DB is SQL server 2008

Comment: Binary is probably the column type (ie. BLOB), it is not a file format. Most likely the contents of the BLOB is an image format, like JPEG or BMP. If so, just write the content of each BLOB to a file. It's probably easier if you just try. :-) If not, come back with more detail.